# SQL Server 2008 - With Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance, with-statement, with-clause

In the Oracle database we had extensively used WITH clause in earlier project.

Now we are on SQL Server 2008 database. Do you suggest we can still use the WITH Clause in our SQL codes ? Does SQL Server 2008 support WITH clause ?

I mean does it improve the performance or does using WITH affect query performance in SQL Server 2008 ?

Comment: `Sql Server 2008` supports `With` clause. Without looking at how it is used we cannot really say how it will perform.

Comment: could you show some example queries?

Comment: i use WITH quite often on SQL Server - without any troubles

Comment: It will depend entirely on what you are doing with your CTE (the proper name for a `with` clause in SQL server), but should behave either with more or the same level of efficiency as `from (select...)`

Comment: @Esteban P. If you use it without any troubles it does not mean *all the people* use it without troubles. I had to rewrite much code that did not perform well because there were 10-20 nested CTE and the server was not able to estimate cardinality well. I had to split all this code using temporary tables in order to take the server a chance to do the correct estimates

Comment: @sepupic you're right. but as the question is not specific at all, there couldn't be any precise answer ;-)

Comment: The question is so generic that we cannot be sure even if it says about CTE %) The WITH clause is not used only in CTE and that's why it requires ";" before it for correct parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more about it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

and here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table

Depending on what it is you were specifically looking at.

Performance is very much dependent on what it is you are doing, you would need to post some examples.